# Can't see the new advanced auth dialog with my dev and test users

Tags: facebook, permissions, authentication

I'm trying to get Facebook's new Enhanced Authorization dialog to appear for my dev/test users, and it's been really problematic. When the Enhanced Authorization dialog doesn't appear, I can't get the `publish_actions` permission for the user's account, and my app doesn't work.

What I've tried:

- I've checked the "Enhanced Auth Dialog" option in app parameters.
- I've created two Aggregations with sample values.
- I've put `publish_actions` for user and friends in the Authenticated Referral request, and `publish_stream` in the extended permissions the app requests.

What's strangest to me is that with my admin account, I saw the Enhanced Auth dialog when I logged in the first time, and *I* have the `publish_actions` permission.

Here's the code that I'm currently using - this block is the JS embedded in a page that should generate the Enhanced Auth dialog.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : '334890956523886', // App ID
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});

// Additional initialization code here
  };

 // Load the SDK Asynchronously
 (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
 </script>

<fb:add-to-timeline show-faces="true" perms="publish_actions,publish_stream"></fb:add-to-timeline>
```

The page's `<html>` tag is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      dir="ltr" lang="fr-FR" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

This is the URL for the auth dialog that my app's PHP code produces:

```
http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=334890956523886&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fzewishlist%2F&response_type=none&display=page&perms=publish_stream%2Cpublish_actions&auth_referral=1
```

Comment: Is everything setup in `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<app_id>/auth`? Also can you paste the code your using to generate the auth URL (js or php).

Comment: @nav i've filled headline, description in customize section, and publish_actions in user &friends permissions,publish_stream in extended permissiosn fields. i edit my question and put the code js a i use pour the authentication url

Comment: I dont see any js code in your original post :S

Comment: @nav, yep, it takes more times i thought

Comment: @nav i use also php code in an other part of the program, but those code was used with succes last week, and i (dev and test users also) can see the new enhanced dialog auth. but since monday test and dev who suppress the app for testing can't reconnect to it with the right auth dialog. I haven't suppres the app from my admin profil , cause i d'ont want loose my publish_action permission. For me it seems that the problem is on the backoffice of the app (auth/aggregations), but i can't find a solutions in the post i've read

Comment: And if you go to http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=applications and open up your selected app you see 'Publish games and app activity' permission for you but none of your test/dev users? It may sound crazy but you could try changing your application category to a game - at the start this was the only category `publish_actions` perm would show up for, they may have reverted it for sandboxed applications by mistake or to test..

Comment: Also try for a second to remove the perm `publish_stream` and just keep `publish_actions`

Comment: @nav thank you for your help ! i'll try all of this (some i'ev already done, i'll do it twice. this affair makes me crazy!)

Comment: @nav nothing change, still the same problem....

Comment: For other users' future reference, here's the relevant FB documentation page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/

Comment: 8 days later, i've done nothing .... and it works now. I don't understand what's going on. But it works so , it's great